# Api with endpointType PRIVATE has no resource policy defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I am setting up a private AWS API Gateway, and I configured Resource Policy to allow all traffic as you see below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I applied wildcards in `Principal`, `Action`, and `Resource`, however, I am getting 403 Forbidden error. Also, CloudWatch is logging error `Api with endpointType PRIVATE has no resource policy defined` even though I configured resource policy for the private API.

I followed [this guide to setup resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-policy-language-overview.html), but am I doing something wrong?  Or, does the error message mean something else?

Comment: I just ran into this problem.  I had a resource policy saved, my API deployed, and was still getting this error.  The solution for me was I had to go the the resource policy section in API Gateway, make a meaningless change (insert whitespace), saved, and then re-deployed.  It started working after that....go figure.

Comment: I hit this when using Terraform and everything configured correctly.  Oddly, rerunning the pipeline passed just fine.  It was just that first iteration that failed.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your cloudwatch logging shows a "Api with endpointType PRIVATE has no resource policy defined"suggests that it's not seeing you have saved your resource policy or you haven't [deployed the API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html) after the resources policy changes were made?

Also, note that the resource in your policy is referring to the resource which the Principal is allowed to access (so in other words the API the policy is being applied to). For mine in my test I did this and it works fine after I deploy my API:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:ACCID:APIID/*/*/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

NOTE: You need to set the ACCID and APIID accordingly.